# Read text file directly from sdcard in Android studio using cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-studio, phonegap, file-read

I am working on a project which has a task to read a text file from the sdcard. The file path is given on the code. I tried using this code but no output.

```
 var path = "Download/myfile.txt";

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, success, fail);

function fail(e) {
      console.error(e);
}

function success(fileEntry) {
   fileEntry.file(function(file) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onloadend = function(e) {
           var content = this.result;
           console.log(content);
       };
       reader.readAsText(file); // or the way you want to read it
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 var path = "Download/myfile.txt";
```

with

```
var path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"/Download/myfile.txt;
```

and make sure `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` is there in Android Manifest file.

Comment: did the fail function exexuted ? what does result ?

Comment: 08-04 01:21:06.347 4785-4850/com.siad.test1 E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(264)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
08-04 01:21:06.347 4785-4850/com.siad.test1 E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(417)] No suitable EGL configs found.
08-04 01:21:06.366 4785-4850/com.siad.test1 E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(264)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS